# Android: referencing library project in eclipse is not working after ADT update?

Tags: android

I updated my ADT plugin for the first time in a little while, and I regret it.  Previously, I was able to reference my library project from another project by doing: propteries->android->add (library)->select library project->press ok.  However, now when I do this, nothing happens.  The next time I open my Android properties dialog, the list of referenced libraries is empty.  Suspiciously, I see the library reference in my default.properties file, but not in my project.properties file.

Has anyone run into this and have any idea of a solution?

Comment: After upgrade did you restart eclipse?

Comment: you are going to need to update the project using the android command line tool....check the release notes for r15/16 should have the information to walk you through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default.properties file changed to project.properties and build.properties changed to ant.properties in ADT and tools r14. Any existing projects that you build with Ant must be updated with the "android update project" command. Eclipse should update the projects when opening them, but you might want to just try creating a new android project and re-importing the existing source if all else fails.